# data is not inserted correctly in csv

Tags: php, csv

When i add data into csv programmatically it gives me below issue:

Please check attached screen shot first:

I have some columns in my csv file. Crad#, current balance, amount used and etc..

Please not that, Ship_to_Adddress_1, Ship_to_Adddress_2, Ship_to_Adddress_3 do not have any data. from csv.

The issue is related to Ship_to_Name column. This column contains customer first name and last name.

Here (Demo demo is the customer name)... When I genearte the csv the Demo demo should display under column Ship_to_Name only.

But it is displaying first name in one column and the last name in another column.

It should display under Ship_to_Name column.

According to me space between Demo demo is the main issue.

Following is the code:

```
$fileName = "Zitomer_used_cards_".$fileDate."_".$trxntime.".csv";
$file = "/abc/abc/staging.abc.com/abc/code/testworks/csv/".$fileName;

    if (!(file_exists($file))) {
     $csv_handler = fopen ($file,'w'); 
     fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv);
     fclose ($csv_handler);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show that the content of `$csv` is (something like `print_r($csv);`)

Comment: If your name field is in the format `firstname, lastname` the comma will be picked up as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Is your data set collected in an array?
First, ensure that surname and name are concatenated or glued without any comma among them, i.e. 
    $data = array('bla','blah',$surname.' '.$name);

Then, there are specific statements for csv file generation, such as fputcsv http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php: it reads from array and inserts into csv row by row